# Punching several tons above my weight

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Is there a more commonly used phrase or idiom other than

> I've punched several tons above my weight

Of course, I know the original expression is "I've punched above my weight" but I need to emphasise just how much!

The context of this:

"Hey guys, I just had a date with [X], I have to say I've punched several tons above my weight!" meaning that I went out with someone who is much more attractive than someone I could usually date due to my relatively less nice appearance.

Comment: Given that no prizefighter weighs anything like even *half* a ton, it's hard to imagine how anything could be much more emphatic than *several tons* higher than that. You could perhaps quantify your pugilistic prowess terms of [Whales](http://www.amazon.co.uk/How-Many-Elephants-Blue-Whale/dp/1402780478) or [Wales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unusual_units_of_measurement#Wales), which are both well-established "quirky yardsticks".

Comment: @FumbleFingers But this has nothing to do with weight. The expression is used eg. when you date someone much better looking than you.

Comment: "I rised to a fascinating/considerable/difficult/major challenge".

Comment: @StopUsingFacebook: You should include that meaning in your question text, if you're specifically interested in that particular metaphoric extension. Again metaphorically derived from the sporting context, you might say you're dating someone *well out of your league*, which at least might help avoid the unwanted connotations of you being a potential wife/girlfriend beater.

Comment: Hey, you're way out of your league/depth.

Comment: I’ve never heard this expression. And it doesn’t really make much sense.  I could see, “I’m fighting way above my weight.” as a boxing metaphor for being out of your class.

Comment: Avoid using 'punch' in that context. 'Punch' has a slang sexual meaning. Or maybe you mean to say you bedded somebody or something that weighed several tons more than you do?

Comment: Technically you are talking about punching several [weight classes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weight_class_(boxing)) above your weight, not several tons. Whether this would be a good way to boast about your dating prowess, I have no idea. I imagine this might work if your group of buddies are both boxing and English language enthusiasts. ;-)

Comment: Punching above one's weight is a common idiom in English as far as my personal experience goes (and I'm certainly no boxer - SE England/London). 'Out of one's league' always had an AmE ring to it. If you want to add emphasis try adding 'well,' as in: I'm punching well above my weight.

Answer (score 1):

**Out of my league** or **WAY Out of my league** to add a sporting metaphor

Comment: There was a wonderful line in the otherwise forgettable 2004 movie *The Librarian: Quest for the Spear,* in which the decidedly fetching female lead parries a timidly tepid advance by the rather nebbish-y male one, saying "I'm way out of your league. Way out. If your league were to explode, I wouldn't hear the sound for another three days." ([Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0412915/quotes?ref_=tt_ql_3).)

Comment: That's brilliant !

Answer (score 0):

> I attacked a battalion of heavyweights with my featherweight fists.
>
> I bit off a cartload more than I could chew.

Comment: Thanks but that really changes the intended meaning. I was hoping for the same base expression.

Comment: @StopUsingFacebook: Give us more context then.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps **I got above my station**, i.e. higher than is suitable for my position or rank.

Answer (score 0):

*Hey guys, I just had a date with [X], I have to say she's [**nowhere near in the same league**](https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&site=&source=hp&q=jouer+dans+la+cour+des+grands+anglais&oq=jouer+dans+la+cour+d&gs_l=tablet-gws.1.1.0i19l3.3851.15927.0.18068.23.17.2.4.4.0.404.2483.0j4j4j1j1.10.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..7.15.2249.0.WpWbDBTY1SQ#q=%22nowhere+near+in+the+same+league%22&prmd=ivn&start=0)/she isn't [**anywhere near in the same league**](https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&site=&source=hp&q=jouer+dans+la+cour+des+grands+anglais&oq=jouer+dans+la+cour+d&gs_l=tablet-gws.1.1.0i19l3.3851.15927.0.18068.23.17.2.4.4.0.404.2483.0j4j4j1j1.10.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..7.15.2249.0.WpWbDBTY1SQ#q=%22isn%27t+anywhere+near+in+the+same+league%22) as I am!"*

> not be in the same league:  to be not as good as someone or something ​else [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/dicionario/ingles/not-be-in-the-same-league)